# Sort a two dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, sorting

Can anyone tell the difference between

1. Arrays.sort(points, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]));
2. Arrays.sort(points, (a, b) ->{ return a[1] - b[1]; });

Comment: The second one is buggy due to integer overflow for some array values.

Answer (score -2):

These are (essentially) functionally the same, as per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int))

Integer.compare(x, y) returns "the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y"

Comment: Actually ... they are NOT the same.

Comment: They are the same provided the operands/arguments have an absolute difference less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Otherwise, subtraction may lead to overflow.